# How to convert all dict key from str to float

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have got this current dictionary :

```
mydict = { "123.23":10.50, "45.22":53, "12":123 }
```

and I would to get this dictionary (with key as float):

```
mydict = { 123:23:10.50, 45.22:53, 12:123 }
```

I know that I can iterate over key and recreate a new dict like this:

```
new_dict = {}
for k in mydict.keys():
    new_dict[float(k)]=mydict[k]
```

but I expect that it may be possible to convert dict key "inline" ( without to have to recreate a new dict ) ...

What is the most efficient method to do it ?

Comment: Just use a simple dict comprehension:
`my_dict=mydict = { "123.23":10.50, "45.22":53, "12":123 }
# using dict comprehension.
my_dict={float(i):j for i,j in my_dict.items()}
print(my_dict) # {123.23: 10.5, 45.22: 53, 12.0: 123}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a **dictionary comprehension**, which is easy to understand, as follows:

```
my_dict = { "123.23":10.50, "45.22":53, "12":123 }
my_dict = {float(i):j for i,j in mydict.items()}

print(my_dict) # {123.23: 10.5, 45.22: 53, 12.0: 123}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use comprehension :

```
new_dict =  { float(k): v for k, v in mydict.items() }
```

Answer (score -1):

> I expect that it may be possible to convert dict key "inline" ( **without to have to recreate a new dict** ) ...
>
> What is the **most efficient** method to do it ?

Unless it materially matters to your runtime and you have time to waste profiling things and trying out various configurations, I'd strongly recommend just creating a second dict using a dict comprehension and focusing on actually relevant concerns: because dict views are "live" updating the dict as you iterate the keys directly may have odd side-effects e.g. you might find yourself iterating it twice as you first iterate the original keys, then try the keys you added; or the iteration might break entirely as deletions lead to internal storage compaction and the iterator gets invalidated.

So to change the key types without creating a new dict, you need to first *copy* the keys to a list, then iterate that and *move* values from one key to another:

```py
for k in list(mydict.keys()):
    mydict[float(k)] = mydict.pop(k)
```

However because of the deletions this may or may not be more efficient than creating a new dict with the proper layout, so the "optimisation" would be anything but.